# Azure Data Factory Flows

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

my Data Factory Gateway (Azure IR) is having troubles to connect to cloud, this happens only when I try to use service principals to authenticate to data lake, in my case I have local (on promise)  proxy, I think that i need to add exception on the proxy to some endpoints (like *.login.windows.net), but I don't have the list of all endpoints that i should allows. can you help me with a list please.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the instructions described here for configuring your corporate firewall and windows firewall on the IR machine:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#ports-and-firewall